# Invoking a tuple containing both the invocable and the arguments

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to invoke the first parameter in a tuple with the second one as a parameter, but can't figure out how to do it.

Example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

struct S {
    void operator()(int) {}
};

int main() {
    S s;
    auto t = std::make_tuple(s, 3);
    std::invoke(s, 3);
    // std::apply(std::invoke, t); // This is what I want to do
    // std::apply(std::invoke<S, int>, t); // I would settle for this "Good Enough"
}
```

but the code above doesn't compile, and the error is very unhelpful (to me):

> error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(void (&)(S&&, int&&), std::__tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<S, int> >&, std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<S, int> >&)'

(this is from the "good enough" attempt)

Anyone know how to do this, or if it can't be done?

Comment: `std::bind` is probably the function you are looking for (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: `std::apply` expects a callable, and a tuple of parameters.  You will need to split your tuple into these two components in order to use `std::apply`..

Comment: @DrewDormann I am supplying it with a callable (`std::invoke<S, int>`) and a tuple (`t`)

Comment: @Austin Yes, that is exactly what it should be doing. Why wouldn't `s(3)` work?

Comment: @Baruch but your tuple is not a _tuple of parameters_.  It contains `s`, which is not a parameter to any callable here.

Comment: @DrewDormann it is a tuple of paramters to `std::invoke`. see the call in the line above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrapping overload/template function in lambda solves lot of issues:

```
std::apply([](auto&&... args){ std::invoke(args...); }, t);
```

Possibly with forwarding:

`std::invoke(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);`

Else as [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is a template function (taking forwarding reference), you need to correct type:

```
std::apply(std::invoke<S&, int&>, t);
std::apply(std::invoke<S, int>, std::move(t));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7oGzGfhPv)

About the error reading: `std::__tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<S, int> >&` is `S&`, so error simplify to

> error: no matching function for call to `__invoke(void (&)(S&&, int&&), S&, int&)`"

You would need `void (&)(S&, int&)` (or pass `S&&`, `int&&` as argument of the function)

Comment: This works, but I would like to understand why this is needed

Comment: @Baruch take a look on documentation what `std::invoke` and `std::apply` do. Basically in this solution unpacks type gets function form first element and then invokes it by passing remaining tuple elements as arguments.

Comment: @Baruch: expanded the answer for direct call to `std::invoke`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Taking some assumption liberties then, one could do `template <typename ...T> void apply_invoke(std::tuple<T...> t) { std::apply(std::invoke<T...>, std::move(t)); }` and call it as `apply_invoke(t);` (Disclaimer:  my template-fu is weak.)

Answer (score 3):

`std::apply` is an option, but you need to use a lambda to invoke `f` appropriately:

```
std::apply([](auto f, auto... args) { 
      std::invoke(f, args...);
    }, t);
```

The reason why `std::apply(std::invoke<S, int>, t)` doesn't work is that `std::invoke` is instantiated as `std::invoke(S&&, int&&)`. Since `t` is an lvalue, it cannot bind to an rvalue reference.

Comment: This works, but I would like to understand why this is needed